# How to merge stashed file to current branch

Tags: git, github

I evacuate files by `git stash -a`

after that I tried `git pull`

And then,I'd like to merge stashed file to current branch

```
$ git stash show stash@{0}
 api/src/attendance/attendance.controller.spec.ts | 18 +++++
 api/src/attendance/attendance.controller.ts      | 20 ++++++
 api/src/attendance/attendance.module.ts          | 13 ++++
 api/src/attendance/attendance.service.spec.ts    | 18 +++++
 api/src/attendance/attendance.service.ts         | 83 ++++++++++++++++++++++++
 api/src/attendance/dto/attendance.dto.ts         | 82 +++++++++++++++++++++++
 api/src/config/CustomNamingStrategy.ts           | 26 ++++++++
 api/src/entities/attendance.entity.ts            | 47 ++++++++++++++
 api/src/entities/condition.entity.ts             | 46 +++++++++++++
 api/src/entities/defecation.entity.ts            | 40 ++++++++++++
 api/src/entities/food.entity.ts                  | 40 ++++++++++++
 api/src/entities/notice.entity.ts                | 43 ++++++++++++
 api/src/entities/sleep.entity.ts                 | 46 +++++++++++++
 api/src/entities/temperature.entity.ts           | 40 ++++++++++++
 api/src/health/dto/health-info-filter.ts         | 20 ++++++
 api/src/health/health-item.enum.ts               |  9 +++
 api/src/health/health.controller.ts              | 13 ++++
 api/src/health/health.module.ts                  | 17 +++++
 api/src/health/health.service.ts                 | 16 +++++
 api/src/notices/dto/notice.dto.ts                | 15 +++++
 api/src/notices/notice.service.spec.ts           | 18 +++++
 api/src/notices/notice.service.ts                | 23 +++++++
 api/src/notices/notices.controller.spec.ts       | 18 +++++
 api/src/notices/notices.controller.ts            | 16 +++++
 api/src/notices/notices.module.ts                | 13 ++++
 api/src/repositories/attendance.repository.ts    |  7 ++
 api/src/repositories/notices.repository.ts       |  7 ++
 27 files changed, 754 insertions(+)
```

And then I tried

`git stash apply stash@{0}`

```
 $ git stash apply stash@{0}
api/src/app.module.ts: needs merge
api/src/entities/user.entity.ts: needs merge
api/src/main.ts: needs merge
```

But it seems that some files was not poped and merged.

it seems `attendance` directory is not emerged.

As I am beginner,how do I recover and merge this stash ?

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of the sentence "which is I created newly and not staged." Could you please explain in more details what result you expected, and what part does not fit this expectation ?

Comment: also : for the context, was there any error message when you ran `git stash apply` ? if yes, can you add this message to your question ?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear, but I suspect you have files in your working directory that have never  been added to git.  You need to stage them. (eg. 'git add file')

Comment: If you're new to Git, I recommend *avoiding* `git stash`. It makes some commits—which is something that you can do with simpler commands—and in some of its more complex invocations, including `git stash -a`, actually *using* those commits can be very tricky. If you make your own commits, rather than letting `git stash` make special and tricky ones, you'll be in much better shape for understanding what is going on. Of course, at this point, it's a little late for that...